# CSS Force nested child behind parent with position:fixed

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have a fixed menu bar that contains a simple `<ul> <li>` menu system. Upon `li:hover` I have a sub-menu system aside appear, and this is relative to each li. Unfortunately this aside is always appearing on top of all of the parents.

When I actually want it to be positioned behind the `div#sidebar`. Is this possible? I have not had much luck with `z-index` (including -1), any help would be appreciated!

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <nav class="secondary">
            <h2>Featured</h2>
            <ul>
                    <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <h3>Title</h3>
                </a>
                        <aside class="article-card">
                            <h4>TITLE</h4>
                            <h5>TEXT</h5>
                        </aside>
                    </li>
            </ul>
    </nav>
</div>


ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 59.6%;
    margin-right: 9.1%;
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

li {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

#sidebar {
    background: #253e40;
    color: #8b8c91;
    width: 215px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 215px;
    margin-right: -215px; /* "#sidebar" width */
    z-index: 3;
}

#sidebar.active { margin-right: 0; }

#sidebar header {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 30px 20px 50px 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #8b8c91;
    color: #8b8c91;
}

#sidebar footer {
    background: none;
    bottom: 40px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    position: absolute;
}

/* Nav */
#sidebar nav {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px 0 50px 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

#sidebar ul {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#sidebar li {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 2px 20px;
}

#sidebar li:before {
    content: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.current-menu-item {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
}

#sidebar a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

#sidebar nav.secondary h2 {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 20px 15px 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #8b8c91;
}

#sidebar nav.secondary li {
    padding: 15px 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #8b8c91;
}

#sidebar nav.secondary li:hover {
    background: #252f37;
    color: #fff;
}

/* Article Card Popout */
.article-card {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #44484f;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    right: 15px;
    border-left: 5px solid #be572b;
}

#sidebar nav.secondary li:hover .article-card {
    right: 215px;
}

.article-card h4 {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px;
}

.article-card h5 {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}

/* Transition animations */
#sidebar,
.article-card {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6zy3d3jq/2/)

Comment: You should position the menu bar itself too. `position:relative` will do. Then you can z-index everything at your leisure. But why do you want the submenu under the menu? Won't it be, you know, hidden?

Comment: Your HTML is also invalid...links cannot be children of a `ul`...only `li`

Comment: @Paulie_D We'll get to that later, when we interrogate the OP about where the missing h3 is.

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D. Code updated!

Comment: @MrLister thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately this isn't resolving the problem (as far as I can see). Are you able to update the Fiddle? I need the aside behind the #sidebar to hide and then reveal on li:hover.

Comment: @dungey_140 Check my answer if I got your problem correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want to keep that html, you need to create a new stacking context. `#sidebar` has `position:fixed` - elements inside sidebar are treated with a new stacking context that now begins at #sidebar and not at `body` level any more. 
Children of the sidebar cannot be positioned below `#sidebar`.

To solve this add another container inside sidebar that contains all the `background` styling and is inside the same stacking context as your slideout.

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 59.6%;
    margin-right: 9.1%;
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

li {
 display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

#sidebar {
 background: #253e40;
 color: #8b8c91;
    width: 215px;
 height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
 right: 215px;
 margin-right: -215px; /* "#sidebar" width */
 z-index: 3;
}

#sidebar.active { margin-right: 0; }

.sidebar-content {
    height: 100%;
  background: #253e40;  
}

#sidebar header {
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 30px 20px 50px 20px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #8b8c91;
 color: #8b8c91;
}

#sidebar footer {
 background: none;
 bottom: 40px;
 padding: 0 20px;
 position: absolute;
}

/* Nav */
#sidebar nav {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 20px 0 50px 0;
 display: inline-block;
}

#sidebar ul {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
}

#sidebar li {
 margin-bottom: 0;
 padding: 2px 20px;
}

#sidebar li:before {
 content: none;
 padding: 0;
}

.current-menu-item {
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #fff;
}

#sidebar a:hover {
 color: #fff;
}

#sidebar nav.secondary h2 {
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 0 20px 15px 20px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #8b8c91;
}

#sidebar nav.secondary li {
 padding: 15px 20px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #8b8c91;
}

#sidebar nav.secondary li:hover {
 background: #252f37;
 color: #fff;
}

/* Article Card Popout */
.article-card {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1; // z index put's it below .sidebar-content
    background-color: #44484f;
    display: inline-block;
 width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    right: 15px;
    border-left: 5px solid #be572b;
}

#sidebar nav.secondary li:hover .article-card {
 right: 215px;
}

.article-card h4 {
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 10px;
}

.article-card h5 {
 color: #fff;
 padding: 10px;
}

/* Transition animations */
#sidebar,
.article-card {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;

}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-content">
    <nav class="secondary">
         <h2>Featured</h2>
   <ul>
    <a href="#">
                    <li>Title
                        <aside class="article-card">
                         <h4>TITLE</h4>
                            <h5>TEXT</h5>
                        </aside>
                    </li>
                </a>
   </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you @easwee so much for your considered and explained solution. This works perfectly - I really appreciate you taking the time. Hopefully this will aide others too.

Comment: @dungey_140 no problem - glad to help.